# Como somar as 2 primeiras ocorrências de uma coluna usando uma chave como referência no SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá, tenho a seguinte tabela:

```sql
create table events (
    type int not null,
    value int not null,
    time datetime
    unique(type, time)
);
```

Onde na mesma eu tenho os seguintes registros:

```
------------------------------------------
| type | value | time                    |
------------------------------------------
|2     | 5     | 2015-05-09 12:42:00.000 | 
|4     | -42   | 2015-05-09 13:19:57.000 |
|2     | 2     | 2015-05-09 14:48:30.000 |
|2     | 7     | 2015-05-09 12:54:39.000 |
|3     | 16    | 2015-05-09 13:19:57.000 |
|3     | 20    | 2015-05-09 15:01:09.000 |
------------------------------------------
```

Eu preciso que, para todo evento que houver mais de uma ocorrência, eu pegue os dois últimos eventos registrados e retorne a diferença entre os seus valores.

Por exemplo, para o evento do tipo 2, eu teria que retornar a 1ª e a 4ª linha, além de calcular a diferença entre os valores (5 - 7 = -2) e retornar na tabela.

Para listar os eventos recorrentes, estou usando a SQL abaixo:

```sql
select
    type,
    (select top 1 value 
     from events 
     where type = e.type 
     order by time desc
    ) - (select value 
         from events 
         where type = e.type 
         order by time desc 
         offset 1 rows fetch next 1 row only) as value
FROM events e
group by type
having count(type) > 1
```

O problema é que eu não tenho noção de como eu consigo retornar somente as 2 primeiras ocorrências de cada evento e fazer o cálculo entre os valores do primeiro e do segundo.

Pra resolver meu problema, eu fui obrigado a fazer 2 consultas como resultado para um valor na tabela. O problema que isso não é otimizado pois são 2 SELECT's a mais e que (não é possível que não exista) deve ter alguma forma melhor de se fazer...

Existe alguma forma de otimizar isso? De não precisar fazer as 2 SQL para somar os 2 últimos `value` das 2 ocorrências da tabela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia.

A solução para o seu caso seria a utilização de uma common-table-expression.

No exemplo dado existe uma inconsistência na escrita, você desejaria os mais recentes ou os mais antigos? Dada a resposta ainda existe a necessidade de executar uma alteração na query, somente no `order by` do `row_number`.

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT p.type, 
           p.value, 
           p.time,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.type 
                                 ORDER BY p.time DESC) AS rk
      FROM eventos p)
 select t.type, (select value from summary p where p.rk = 1 and p.type = t.type) - 
             (select value from summary p where p.rk = 2 and p.type = t.type)
   from summary t
  where t.rk < 3
    and exists (
         select e.type, COUNT(1)
           from eventos e
          where e.type = t.type
          group by e.type
         having COUNT(1) > 1)
  group by t.type
```

Segue documentação do SQL Server: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017